# Laravel form action comes with space in live server

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I was trying to submit form data with a bootstrap modal. The form works OK in locally means i can submit data. But in live server it comes with space so i can't submit the data with the same form what could be possible error for that?

Here is the route:

```
Route::post('storeCart','CheckoutController@storeCart')->name('storeCart');
```

**Here is the source i have used for form (blade view):**

```
  <form action="{{route('storeCart')}}" method="post">
  </form>
```

**Live server version the form shows like this when i inspect the element :**

```
 <form action=" http:="" abc.co="" storecart"="" method="post">
 </form>
```

**Local version the form shows like this when i inspect the element:**

```
<form action="http://localhost/abc/public/storeCart" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: set the APP_URL in your .env

Comment: I changed it with the actual domain in .env file

Comment: action=" http:=""   you have a also a typo

Comment: `<form action="{{url('storeCart')}}" storecart"="" method="post">
 </form>` try this

Comment: I have updated my question with source.

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` may be its the cache

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz that might have been generated by Laravel as the TS said.

Comment: "_I changed it with the actual domain in .env file_" Did you run `php artisan config:clear` afterwards?

Comment: Yes. I have run the php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Laravel Core](https://github.com/laravel/framework) not working properly. Update composer by using `SSH`:

```
composer update --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

Then run those commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: I have run the above command you instructed But the problem is it's not working. Means  the problem i'm facing have told in question same problem i'm still facing.